# Django JsonResponse customize its header

Tags: json, django, header, response, jsonresponse

I want to change response header of

```
> from django.http import JsonResponse
```

function for example change Date header
how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter it as a key-value dictionary, so:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

response = JsonResponse()
response['Date'] = 'some value'
return response
```